# How to fix TypeError: this.state is null?

Tags: reactjs

I am in learning phase of react.js and I am trying to replicate whole div on click of button. where do i need to change state in my code. Respective button should accordingly too. Add button to add div. Remove button to remove added div.

````
      class ReplicateDiv extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = { array: [] };
      this.manageDiv = this.manageDiv.bind(this);
       }
      manangeDiv(e, type) {


        const { array } = this.state.array;

        if (type === "add") {
          array.push(array[0]);
        } else if (type === "remove") {
          array.splice(0, 1);
        }
        this.setState({
          array
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={e => this.manangeDiv(e, "add")}>
              add
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={e => this.manangeDiv(e, "remove")}>
              remove
            </button>
            {this.state.array.map((item, index) => {
              return <div key={index}> Dynamic Div </div>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: 1. @Roopak below has a part of the solution. Do that. 
2. You can eliminate line 3. 
3. On line 5 - here's a correct way to do it: `const { array } = this.state;`

Comment: @kiran - I have posted answer below. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `constructor` you need to initialize the state variable.

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {array: [] };

  }
```

Comment: class AddDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      array: []
    });
    this.manangeDiv = this.manangeDiv.bind(this);
  }

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to change for this to work **properly**.

As another user stated, you have to create a constructor like below, where you can also bind your `manageDiv`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { array: [] };
    this.manageDiv = this.manageDiv.bind(this);
  }
```

Another thing you have to change is the state destruction on your `manageDiv` function to `const { array } = this.state;`

Finally and **most importantly** both `push` and `splice` are mutating the array directly which is not what you want to do on react. Your state should only be changed using `this.setState`. If you comment

```
    this.setState({
      array
    });
```

you will be able to see that the `push` and `splice` have already change your array, before even calling `this.setState`. You should consider using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead, creating a new array where changes will take place, and then change your state with this new array.

Answer (score 0):

Things to remember in react:-

1) **Never mutate array**

2) Always use **correct `this`** in functions by **binding** the function in constructor or using **arrow functions**.

**Working code below:-**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    custom: ["div1"]
  };
  manangeDiv = type => e => {
    let cDivs = this.state.custom;
    if (type === "add") {
      cDivs.push("newDiv");
    } else if (type === "remove") {
      cDivs.pop();
    }
    this.setState({ custom: cDivs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.manangeDiv("add")}>
          add
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.manangeDiv("remove")}>
          remove
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.custom.map((item, index) => {
          return <div key={index}>Dynamic Div</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!